# flutter_stripe: CardFormField shows blank form when phone is in dark mode

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, darkmode, flutter-stripe

I have followed the steps of configuring the flutter_stripe package correctly as mentioned [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe#:%7E:text=Requirements-,Android,-This%20plugin%20requires).

The problem is that my phone is in dark mode, and when I use the CardFormField provided from the flutter_stripe package, it shows a blank form, and when I put the phone in light mode, the form is shown without any problems.

Here are my configuration files:

**Project-level build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Light styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode
    setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Night styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode
    setting is on -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```